# How to change order of the menu items of the modules into mean.io?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean.io

I had added each module of my application to the menu of mean.io, into of the app.js file like this:

```
Theme.menus.add({
    title: 'theme example page',
    link: 'theme example page',
    roles: ['authenticated'],
    menu: 'main'
});
```

All modules are shown in my menu, but the order is wrong, How can change that order?

Comment: I would like to know this too. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @tkarls, I fix that with this pull request but I don't know if they accepted this change, but if you would like to review this fix you can go to this link: https://github.com/linnovate/meanio/pull/79/commits/18a6dc03c6f0ecb2170feaebbf2de00df13ab0cc, I put a new attribute "order" that is a number.

Comment: Hi @christmo, great stuff. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the order of the menu that you are adding.

For example:

```
function menuConfig(Menus) {
   Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', {
      title: 'Cuentas',
      state: 'accounts',
      type: 'dropdown',
      roles: ['*'],
      position: 1
    });
}
```

You need to use the attribute >> position.

position (Optional; Default: 0) - Specify the order of appearance.